# Signal strength for scapy beacon packet, negative Integer to two's complement hex

Tags: python, hex, scapy, twos-complement, negative-number

I am trying to convert a negative integer to a two's complement hex that can be put into the hex code of a scapy packet (bellow) in the signal_strength variable.

The negative number comes from this line of code:

```
    sigstren = int(-1*(20*math.log10(distance) + 20*math.log10(frequency) - 37.55))
```

An example number is -54, whose hex two's complement is FFCA, but I need it in the format of \xca.

```
RadioTap(len=18, present='Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+Antenna', notdecoded='\x00\x6c' +  get_frequency(CHANNEL) + '\xc0\x00' + signal_strength + '\x01\x00\x00')
```

I have tried this:

```
    signal_string = struct.pack("<h", signal)
```

but it returns \xca\xff which is too big for the packet.

I have also tried this:

```
    def int_to_hex_string(value, bits):
        return "{0:0{1}X}".format(value & ((1<<bits) - 1), bits//4)
    signalstrength = int_to_hex_string(sigstren, 8)
```

but that only returns CA, which I cannot add \x to because of ValueError: invalid \x escape.
I was getting that error when trying to add \x to get the right format for the packet:

```
    signal_strength = '\x' + signalstrength
```

Comment: Post the code that causes the ValueError

Comment: Seems you want the strength as signed byte, not signed short - `signal_string = struct.pack("<b", signal)`

Comment: struct.pack("<b, signal) worked for now, but the new dev version of scapy seems to be a preferred method, if the Keyerror is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know exactly what you are doing, you are trying to populate the radio signal manually into `notdecoded`, because it was not accessible as a field in previous scapy versions.

Note that the latest developpement version of scapy now allows you to access those fields directly. Doing it yourself is more complicated (you also need to take the padding of each field into account...)

- Install the dev version: [zip of latest dev github version](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip) then extract it and `python setup.py install` (with Sudo on Linux)
- Use the newest RadioTap abilities:

Here is the list of fields you can set with the latest dev version of scapy

['TSFT',
 'Flags',
 'Rate',
 'Channel',
 'FHSS',
 'dBm_AntSignal',
 'dBm_AntNoise',
 'Lock_Quality',
 'TX_Attenuation',
 'dB_TX_Attenuation',
 'dBm_TX_Power',
 'Antenna',
 'dB_AntSignal',
 'dB_AntNoise',
 'RXFlags',
 'ChannelPlus',
 'MCS',
 'A_MPDU',
 'VHT',
 'timestamp',
 'RadiotapNS',
 'VendorNS',
 'Ext']

Here is what you should do

```
RadioTap(len=18, present='Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+Antenna',
    dBm_AntSignal=-54,
    Antenna=0x1)
```

It works:

```
###[ RadioTap dummy ]### 
  version= 0
  pad= 0
  len= 18
  present= Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+Antenna
  Flags= 
  Rate= 0
  Channel= 0
  ChannelFlags= 
  dBm_AntSignal= -54dBm
  Antenna= 1
  notdecoded= ''
```

Comment: I downloaded the new dev version, but I am getting KeyError: 'dBm_AntSignal'  here's my radiotap line                                                                         RadioTap(len=18, present='Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+Antenna',
    dBm_AntSignal = get_sigstrength(distance, CHANNEL), Antenna=0x1, Channel = CHANNEL)

Answer (score 0):

Is this any help?

```
>>> hex(0x100 - 0x54)
'0xac'
```

You just have to flip the half-bytes around and change `0` to `\`

Comment: How would I do this if the 54 came from a variable? (see post edits)